# Android buttons are bigger in Samsung devices

Tags: android, button

When I create a Button in Android using a Button or a TextView with a button style like `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"`, the button looks way bigger (in height) in Samsung devices. I'm wondering why this is happening how I can avoid it.

Comment: that's because each device may have it's own `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"` implemented it's own way.

Comment: `how I can avoid it` - just do not bother, otherwise you will be fixing not your "bug" + your app may start to look "non-standard" on that device.